# Customize DatePickerDialog Xamarin Android (Days Line)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to localize the letters of the days above the datepickerdialog in android.
I already fully localized the application to the desired language. Changed the background etc. For some reason though, the letters of the days ain't changing.

I'm currently trying to alter the dialog via a CustomDatepickRenderer, but haven't found the right properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the custom renderer to set the current configuration.

Custom Renderer:

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer))]
namespace App2.Droid
{
    class DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
    public DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var locale = Locale.English;
        this.Control.TextLocale = locale;
        Resources.Configuration.SetLocale(locale);
    }     
   }
 }
```

The Language of the device is Chinese. Use the code to set the language of the `Days Line` to English.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In the end there was a problem in the culture configuration. When it was set to es-US or es-CL it didn't work, but when it was set to just "es" it changed as supposed to. I ended changing the localization of the whole application, but I like your answer better ^^.